# Proving that $0^\infty$ is not indeterminate?

Tags: calculus, limits

Suppose that $f(x)>0$ for all $x$, and for some $a$ both $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = 0$ and $\lim_{x\to a} g(x) = \infty$ are true. How would I go about proving:
$$\lim_{x\to a} f(x)^{g(x)} = 0$$
I am stuck after attempting to evaluate $\lim_{x\to a} \ln(f(x)^{g(x)})$. After some work, I received $$\lim_{x\to a} \frac{g(x)}{-ln(f(x))}$$ but even though I know $\ln(f(x))$ exists for all $x$, it is hardly a guarantee of continuity or differentiability; $g(x)$ is in a similar situation. Thus, I am reluctant to apply L'Hôpital's rule. May I have a hint as to how I should proceed?

Comment: zero equals negative infinity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $0 \lt \epsilon \lt 1$, show that if $f(x) \lt \epsilon$ and $g(x) > 1$, then $f(x)^{g(x)} \le \epsilon$.  Then explain what that has to do with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the approach you outlined is that if $L=\lim_{x \to a} f(x)^{g(x)}$ and $\ln(L)=\lim_{x \to a} g(x)\ln(f(x))$, there will be a problem if $L=0$ since $\ln(0)$ is undefined. Rather, try to show for that every sequence $\{x_n\}$ converging to $a$, the sequence $f(x_n)^{g(x_n)}$ converges to $0$.

Comment: Shouldn't $ln(f(x))$ exist for all $x$, since $f(x)$ is always greater than $0$? Also, unfortunately I don't quite understand the second part of your comment, as that seems to essentially be the premise of the question.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the definition you gave $f(x)$. Nevertheless, if $L=\lim_{x \to a} f(x)^{g(x)}$ and $\ln(L)=\lim_{x \to a} g(x)\ln(f(x))$ You may run into trouble if $L=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $h(x)=\log \left(f(x)^{g(x)}\right)$

Then (informally) $$h(x) = g(x) \log(f(x))=\frac{\log(f(x))}{1/g(x)} \to \frac{-\infty}{0^+}\equiv -\infty$$

Hence $$f(x)^{g(x)} = \exp(h(x)) \to \exp(-\infty) \equiv 0$$